# Change the data in the old arraylist based on the id of the new arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists as follows

ArrayList 1

```
[
{"id": "01", "price": "5000"},
{"id": "02", "price": "6000"},
{"id": "03", "price": "2300"}
]
```

ArrayList 2

```
[
{"id": "01", "name": "nameA", "price": "0"},
{"id": "02", "name": "nameB", "price": "0" },
{"id": "03", "name": "nameB", "price": "0"}
]
```

the question is, how to change the contents of **price** in ArrayList2 to **price** in ArrayList1 based on **id**, I have tried searching on google but did not get the right results,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are advised to convert the JSON character string in the array to an object, compare the object ID and set the **price**, modify the object attribute, and then convert the object to a JSON character string.

Comment: I've made it up and running fine with no problems, it's the second time you help me